# IDE for assembly on pendrive

Tags: windows, ide, portable-apps, assembly

I need a portable IDE for assembly.
What can you recommend me ?

Comment: Architecture? OS? Etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WinAsm Studio](http://www.winasm.net/winasm-studio-full-package.html) is a great assembly IDE. No installation required and everything comes in a tiny ZIP package. Works great from a portable pendrive.

[image]